# Italic text in Links are not colored

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

For example in [my answer here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8696/should-people-who-answer-a-question-actively-prevent-duplicates/8698#8698), if you open it on your mobile (Or just click `mobile` in the footer on your desktop browser), an italic link would look like this:

[image: Link on mobile]

---

While on the desktop it's like so:

[image: Link on desktop]

---

This is the markup of that link:

```
[those *`apt-get` permission denied* questions][1]
```

The problem is that in the css, `<em>` tags have color set on them:

```
em {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: new mobile SE design as resolved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed in the new SE mobile design.
The following is a screen-shot of an italic link in the mobile view:

[image: Link on new mobile view]